# Cheap monitor with reasonable price

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors

I am looking to buy a monitor for around €130. It doesn't have to have 75hz refresh rate or a VA-panel, TN also suits my needs, but it needs to be at least 24" (or 23.8") and have a resolution of at least 1080p.

Comment: If you can tell me which country you live in I can narrow it down more, but for starters, there's [this.](https://de.pcpartpicker.com/products/monitor/#X=0,13797&W=2300,2500&sort=price&page=1)

Comment: So basically you are just looking for a 24" 1080p TN panel monitor that cost less than €130, correct? What inputs does this monitor need to have?

Comment: I'd like it to have DisplayPort, however, I can also live with HDMI. I'd rather have DisplayPort because my graphics card has three DP-inputs and one HDMI-input.

Comment: @JMY1000 The link you sent me is very useful. I've come up with this: https://de.pcpartpicker.com/product/4BBrxr/aoc-e2460sh-240-1920x1080-60hz-monitor-e2460sh. It looks very good.

Comment: @Thijs365 Are you in Germany? Also, DisplayPort to HDMI cables are very cheap since they're entirely passive.

Comment: I'm not in Germany, but the prices are close enough. I've got two HDMI ports in total, though, because my CPU came with integrated graphics to which I can also connect HDMI.

Comment: An IPS or VA panel for a bit more money would also be great. As long as it doesn't have ghosting.